# My TabContainer which is a CustomControl in asp.net not working on IE-11

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer

Below is the code for the same where I have set the default and selected style for the tab:

```
<cc1:AdvancedTabStrip id="subTs" AutoPostBack="True" runat="server" 
        TabDefaultStyle="background-color:#ffffff;font-family:arial;font-weight:bold;font-size:8pt;color:#000000;width:110;height:21;text-align:center;text-decoration:underline;border-color:#efefef;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;"
        TabSelectedStyle="background-color:#ffffff;color:#000000;text-decoration:none;" >
        <cc1:AdvancedTabItem ID="tabGeneral" Text="General" ControlToShow="pnlGeneral"></cc1:AdvancedTabItem>
        <cc1:AdvancedTabItem ID="tabOpenPeriods" Text="Open Periods" ControlToShow="pnlOpenPeriods"></cc1:AdvancedTabItem>
        <cc1:AdvancedTabItem ID="tabAdvanced" Text="Advanced" ControlToShow="pnlAdvanced"></cc1:AdvancedTabItem>
    </cc1:AdvancedTabStrip>
```

The above code for styling works perfect in other browsers except IE-11
Can anyone please provide solution for the same asap as our customer are chasing for this very badly.

Comment: Attached are the screenshots for the same:                         IE-11_Screenshot: http://www.mediafire.com/view/2at62mebudqdu3r/ScreehshotFrom_IE11.jpg                                                  GoogleChrome_Screenshot: http://www.mediafire.com/view/ms19d74t61lsai7/ScreehshotFrom_GoogleChrome.jpg

Comment: Adding the following contents in my browser file fixed the issue: